# Error in capturing cmd + in Swift

Tags: swift, modifier, nsevent

I am trying to capture cmd - and cmd + key presses in Swift, cmd - works fine but when pressing cmd + I get an error bong sound.

```
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.command) {
        print(event.keyCode)
    }
}
```

Comment: is your `keyDown` called? Command-I in a menu? What is the question?

Comment: No, keyDown is not called for cmd +, only for cmd -, I want to know how to enable cmd + also